# Solving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2te^{-t^2-i\omega t}dt$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I want to solve the given integral, to find the Fourier transform of $2te^{-t^2}$.

So, the integral is

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2te^{-t^2-i\omega t}dt
\end{equation}

I put  $u=-t^2-i\omega t$,  $du=-2t-i\omega$, but I am not sure on how to write the integral with du at this stage, since  du is not simply $2t$, so the ideal form would be:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{u}du
\end{equation}

with $u=-t^2-i\omega t$

So what is the right step here?

Thanks

Comment: Apply integration by parts- the integral $\int 2e^{-t^2-i \omega t} \, dt = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-\omega^2/4} \, \text{erf} \left(t+\frac{i \omega}{2}\right)$ has a known antiderivative in terms of the error function.

Comment: which formula did you use to get that ?

Comment: It appears to me that the formula you used is $\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\omega^2/4}Ei\bigg(-\frac{du}{2}\bigg)$, with $u=-t^2-i\omega t$

Comment: Complete the square of the exponent: $\int 2e^{-\left(t+\frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^2-\frac{\omega^2}{4}}$ then substitute $u=\frac{2t+i w}{2}$ and the result follows from the definition of the error function.

Comment: Thanks for that

Comment: Hey, isn't Fourier transform calculated over $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for that, corrected